# How to use counter question word + か

Tags: grammar, particles, questions

In Tae Kim's grammar guide, it tell you that question word can be appended with か、も、でも to mean different things(誰か someone,　誰も everyone,　誰でも anyone).

Can the same be carried over to counters? For example, is the following valid?

> 幾つ**か**の季節 (I know this one is valid, I've seen it being used, "some seasons")
>
> 何台**か**の車 (Can I use it like this?, "some cars")
>
> 何台の車**か** (Or maybe like this?, "some cars")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

何台かの車 is valid but 何台の車か isn’t.
For example, you can say 何台かの車が走り去った or  何台かの車を買った, but I think 車が何台か走り去った or 車を何台か買った is more natural.